# Dealing with Fast RealTime (every second) Data in C# 4.0 Charts

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, charts

I have to chart out StockPrice ticks (got every minute worstcase or 15 seconds bestcase) in Realtime using C# charting.

But for now I have a file containing the historical prices, and am using it to do analysis.

At every price tick, there is a analysis function which outputs special decision data.

I want to chart every tick and then this decision data also which occurs about every 100 ticks.

Problem i am facing is

1. My program is consuming ticks very fast and chart is having problem in charting hugedata.
2. I took sample of Realtime charting from MS, but it gets filled up pretty fast and only way i can get a useful visual experience is by removing older points (that is the exact thing done in Microsoft provided sample).

But Can i have a scrollable chart where i can select a window of price ticks to be displayed. Rest all is not displayed.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? How is this chart supposed to look like. And how does the data look like? How much data are we talking about? How fast is your analysis function running?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [DynamicDataDisplay](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) for your charts. DynamicDataDisplay (DDD) stays very reactive even when I pump in 5 years of hourly data, so I hope it could help you, DDD is scrollable and zoomable easily.

[I just answered another question with code to use it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090345/dynamic-line-chart-in-c-wpf-application/7092654#7092654)