# Simple Rolling Graph Chart in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my program, I am polling once a second in a dispatcher to receive my current network throughput:

```
private PerformanceCounter netSndCounter =
    new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec");
private PerformanceCounter netRcvCounter =
    new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec");

private void updateTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    netSndCurrent = netSndCounter.NextValue();
    netRcvCurrent = netRcvCounter.NextValue();
}
```

This is working well... However, I want to display this somehow as a graph. Similar to the graphs you see in Windows Task Manager in the performance tab. Are there any simple and light-weight tools I can use to do this?

Is there a good way to do this WITHOUT third-party libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WPF class `ChartPlotter` to make graph.

See: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714591.aspx) and [Dynamic Line chart in C# WPF Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090345/dynamic-line-chart-in-c-sharp-wpf-application) for some examples

Or if you want some thrid party libraries you can have a look to this post: [WPF chart controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577278/wpf-chart-controls)

Comment: Is there any actual documentation for D3? The wiki is dead. And there are no source codes for the samples.